# Clojure evaluate argument of macro

Tags: clojure, macros, pattern-matching, core.match

I am trying to write a macro that generates patterns for the core.match macro.

```
(defmacro match2
  [state i predecessor]
  `(match ~[state]
          [(~(vec (concat (repeat i '_)
                           predecessor
                           '(& r)))
            :seq)] ~i
          :else false))
```

And this works fine if I use it directly with hardcoded *predecessor*:

```
(match2 ["B"] 0 ["B"]) ; 0
```

So far everything is fine, but if I try to pass the *predecessor* using function call:

```
(match2 ["B"] 0 ((fn [] ["B"]))) ; AssertionError Invalid list syntax [] in (fn [] ["B"])
```

The problem is that because match2 is a macro clojure won't evaluate the function call, and will just pass the form as it is. The unevaluated form then goes to core.match (again unevaluated, because core.match is itself a macro) and core.match throws exception because the form is not correct pattern.

How can I force evaluation on macro argument? Or any other workaround?

I was hinted that this is usually done with a second macro, but my attempts yielded no good results.

Comment: Well, there is always 'eval'

Comment: I have updated my answer with a link to some good reading about the type of problem you are having. I encourage you not to take the currently accepted answer as the final say in this matter, as it skirts the actual issue you are having.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`core.match` is a compiler. It turns some forms into executable expressions. The forms it can process must respect a syntax, hence the assert throw. As a macro, it compiles at... compile time. However hard you try, you cannot have it compile the result of runtime expressions.

Even if you manage to get `(fn [] ["B"])` evaluated at compile time so to feed the value to `match`, this is not your goal I presume. What you're trying to do is to feed match with expressions evaluated by your program's logic. Been there, sorry to say it is not possible with `core.match`, which D. Nolen confirmed.

Nevertheless, `matchure` can do just that: create match functions / expressions at runtime, see [`fn-match`](https://github.com/dcolthorp/matchure#fn-match-and-defn-match). It is unmaintained AFAIK but just works. I've patched it some time ago to use clj 1.6, [here](https://github.com/fdserr/matchure).

Comment: I disagree, or at least I don't think that is the problem the OP is having. His is a basic and common issue when getting two macros to interact and learning to get past the non-eval wall of the second macro's arguments.

Answer (score 3):

I see two options. Use eval in your macro.

Or, you could have your macro not call the match macro. Have it call another function which calls the match macro. That will force evaluation en route to match.

Here is a good article to read about this type of problem:

http://amalloy.hubpages.com/hub/Clojure-macro-writing-macros

Comment: The eval approach, I believe, won't work (I tried), because it will just pass the (eval expression) unevalueted to match. The second way, I'm not sure, but again I think it work, because when the genenerated patterns go out of the macro into function and be evaluated, they will cause exception (probably thanks to the underscores and the &).

Comment: No, you should eval at first expansion, then pass that to the quoted macro call you emit, the eval is not itself sent into the macro. But still better to use a helper function as an intermediary, which obviates this.

Comment: Had a downvote to do. This seems contrived, I'd vote up a working example. Peace.

Comment: @FrançoisDeSerres there is so much literature on this very common topic of getting macros to interact with each other. I have linked one very good explanation by amalloy. The downvote was unnecessary. Your answer is just not correct, and is also worthy of a downvote.